# File Repository Module

Tags: files

Is there anybody have ever used a  moudle that like File Repository ? Who can tell me whether have the similar module in Drupal.org ?

This module should provide these following functions :

(1) Authorised user can create folder and sub folder, upload files into a folder.

(2) Role-based access control:
      a) Authorised user can config the attributes of folder, can assign which role can access this folder.
      b)Folder & sub folder both can set different access control attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [filedepot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot) module.

> The filedepot module is full featured Document Management module that
>   has a google docs like feel. It fulfills the need for an integrated
>   file management module supporting role and user based security.
>   Documents can be saved outside the Drupal public directory to protect
>   documents for safe access and distribution.